# Apache Jmeter Recording Controller Uploading file

Tags: java, android, apache, jmeter, httpclient

I'm using Apache Jmeter recording controller utility to access a certain website...when using website normally without jmeter proxy settings and other stuff, website works fine with full functionality....but when using Jmeter proxy settings I'm not able any more to upload to the website and it displays me an error.
any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing from behind a firewall/proxy server, you may need to provide JMeter with the firewall/proxy server hostname and port number. To do so, run the jmeter[.bat] file from a command line.

How to run the .bat file and how to change its parameters can be find in given URL:-

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server

I am sure that should work.